# How to add Stickers in WhatsApp clone app?

Tags: android, whatsapp

[image]I have created a WhatsApp Sticker app for android using demo code provided by WhatsApp Inc. in github. It's work fine with WhatsApp single app. But I can't add my stickers in WhatsApp Clone app. I am testing my app in Honor 9 Lite device. Please help me for how to add stickers in twin or clone WhatsApp? My manifest file code is below which I have used in my app

```
    <provider
            android:name="com.emojistickers.StickerContentProvider"
            android:authorities="${contentProviderAuthority}"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:readPermission="com.whatsapp.sticker.READ" />
```

What is package name use for WhatsApp twin or clone app?

Comment: Since there are many ways to clone WhatsApp and here it's not mentioned which way is used, I can only suggest, try changing the package name in the demo code to match the cloned WhatsApp's package name. However, I'm highly doubtful as to if it will work. And from your question, it seems that you don't know the package name for the cloned WhatsApp. For that, you can go in System Settings and check for the package name. However, if you're using virtual environments like Parallel Space, etc., just cloing the sticker pack might work too. I repeat, I'm not sure.

Comment: @HrishikeshKokate : on my phone, I can't check package name in the system settings.That's why I wanna know package name

Comment: Try using some app to show package name. Or tell how you're cloning the app.

Comment: I have tried to fetch package name by coding but its shows only com.whatsapp as the package name. In adding, i will update screenshot of cloning today

Comment: If the package name is same and it's still not reading it, then probably cloned WhatsApp don't support stickers (yet). However, your screenshot will be of help.

Comment: @HrishikeshKokate : please check my screenshot

Comment: Oh, so, you've created a clone using your system's built-in feature. I have no idea how exactly your system is creating a clone. But, you can try cloning your sticker pack inside it too (if at all your system allows it in some way). Or, you can use other cloning apps like Parallel Space, Island, etc. and clone your WhatsApp as well as the sticker pack in it. That's my best guess. No wonder now why you were unable to get the package name.

Comment: @HrishikeshKokate : Its not showing any package name of twin app that's why I am in trouble to find out the package name of twin

Comment: That's why I said, use some app from Play Store to clone WhatsApp and your sticker pack and see if that works. My suggestions: Island or Parallel Space.

Comment: Sorry its not showing option to add stickers in another whatsapp using parallel space

Comment: That's bad. Well then, I don't have any more options.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly we can't see additional stickers in cloned whatsapp ,so you need to clone that sticker app also add those will apper in your cloned whatsapp ,it worked for me on parallel space

Comment: I have a problem with system based clone Whatsapp. Not checked with parallel space.